# multiple session timeout and different events for them

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to handle multiple session timeouts?

I mean for example if user hasn't accessed page for 30 minutes  - he will see notifications with something like `session data updated` or something.

But if user hasn't accessed page for 1.5 hour - modal window will appear with asking for authentication again.

Comment: It isn't possible to do the first with just a servlet. You would need some JavaScript. The second will happen automatically next time he uses the webapp. It won't happen automatically at the expiry time unless you add JavaScript.

Comment: So basically in order to do it I need to count time on the page using javascript and then do some action? Set `1.5 hour` session timeout and less than 1.5 calculate using javascript?